# launchctl and AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to extract tweets using twitter search api for a specific keyword every 15 mins. I have a launchctl task setup (on Mac OSX 10.9.3). The python script extracts tweets and loads successfully in mongodb. I am using python 2.7 and the twitter package.

But, when I execute the same python script via launchctl, I get the following error.

```
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret,consumer_key,consume_secret)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'
```

Any help on why the code executing via launchctl throws error, while executing the same code in sublime text or ipython works perfectly fine.

Also, here is the PATH env variable.

```
/Users/priya/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to the PATH that `launchctl` is using.

Is the `PATH` from above the one from running

```
launchctl getenv PATH
```

? If not, you could try doing

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```

in terminal, which would set `launchctl`'s PATH to your current `bash` one

Comment: Excellent! Can you flag this answer as correct then?